# Como converter um projeto Java em Eclipse para um projeto Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Tenho um projeto Java em Eclipse que quero converter num projeto Maven.

Para a conversão, eu do um clique com o botão direito do mouse e seleciono a opção *"Convert to Maven Project"* como indicado na figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que após a conversão do projeto a pasta source continua *"src"*. Eu gostaria de deixar como o padrão do Maven, assim como quando criamos um projeto empty do Maven. Exemplo:

```
src/main/java
src/main/test
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ação "Convert to Maven project" do Eclipse apenas cria `Project Object Model` (pom.xml) inicial. O eclipse não altera a estrutura de pastas do seu projeto. Para criar uma pasta `test` basta criar um Folder e depois clicar com o botão direito em `Build path` > `Use as source folder`.

O processo de dependências e plugins (exclusão das classes de test do build por exemplo) precisa ser feita manualmente.