# Usar Projeto java em outro projeto

Tags: java

Eu tenho um projeto java web (uma espécie framework)
e quero usa-lo no meu projeto principal(a aplicação), mas não quero gerar um .jar. quero usar ele direto dentro do meu projeto para que quando eu precise fazer alguma alteração não precise toda fez compilar um .jar. Eu adicionei o projeto em Propriedades > java build path > projects
Consigo usar as classes do outro projeto normalmente, mas ao executar o projeto no navegador eu recebo o erro:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jmsys.client.component.botao.BotaoConfirmar
```

Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Utilize o maven, fica mais facil.  Se você ja utiliza o maven coloque a seguinte dependência.  <dependency>  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> 
  <artifactId>nome do seu projeto</artifactId> 
  <version> versao do seu projeto </version> 
</dependency>

Comment: Certo, eu criei o projeto sem utilizar o mavem, é possivel utilizar ele depois do projeto criado ?

Comment: é possivel sim. Mas faça um backup antes.
segue links

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53706/como-converter-um-projeto-java-em-eclipse-para-um-projeto-maven

Comment: http://maven3tutorial.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/converta-um-projeto-web-do-eclipse-para.html#.V30ncmgrIdU

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, isso me ajudará tbm.

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes, pode me dizer como vc usa a classe do outro projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que está faltando compilar as classes. Se estiver usando o Eclipse vá no menu e selecione: **Project > Clean**. Na caixa que vai abrir selecione **Clean projects selected below**, marque os projetos que está trabalhando e clique em **OK**. Em seguida publique as alterações no servidor. Deve resolver.

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado.